# Enable TRACE for a particular logger in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

How do I setup `logging.properties` to log diverts in `artemis.log`?

I understand that `TRACE` should be used for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.DivertImpl`

How do I set it up in `etc/logging.properties`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable a particular logger (e.g. `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.DivertImpl`) in `logging.properties` you must first add the logger to the `loggers` list at the top of the file. Here is the default `loggers` list with `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.DivertImpl` added:

```
loggers=org.eclipse.jetty,org.jboss.logging,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server,org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils,org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal,org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server,org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap,org.apache.activemq.audit.base,org.apache.activemq.audit.message,org.apache.activemq.audit.resource,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.DivertImpl
```

Then you need to configure the logging level for the logger to `TRACE`, e.g.:

```
logger.org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.DivertImpl.level=TRACE
```

Lastly, you need to update the `level` of the necessary `handler` to allow the `TRACE` logging through, e.g.:

```
handler.CONSOLE.level=TRACE
```

or

```
handler.FILE.level=TRACE
```